# Compiling c with libtasn1.h

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I know a little bit about gcc and am decent with linux but I cannot for the life of me get my c program with libtasn1 to compile. I downloaded the package from the website and then tried to compile and I get nothing. I even tried sudo apt-get install libtasn1-3-bin and that did not help either. I really have no clue what else to try, but I am beginning to think I need to add some sort of linking to GCC but like I said I am really unsure. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: How have you compiled it? What errors did gcc output? Please add to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install libtasn1-3-dev
```

and compile (link, actually) your program with

```
gcc ... -ltasn1
```

By the way, according to the nameing convention of Debian, package names ended with `-dev` usually include the files, such as header files, dynamic libraries, needed for development.